# DotNET String comparisons

Tags: string, comparison

After a few harsh lessons I now always use OrdinalIgnoreCase when comparing Strings in DotNET. I've run into maybe 5 different problems to do with numerics, weird alphabets and localisations. Does anyone know of a good site that explains in depth a lot of the problems with culture specific Strings, preferably with a bunch of good examples of where and how something can fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of MSDN info:

- [String-Related Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292178(VS.71).aspx)
- [Best Practices for Developing World-Ready Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7x1y988.aspx)
- [New recommendations for Using strings in .Net 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx)
- [Performing Culture-Insensitive String Comparisons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/885e1sy1(VS.100).aspx)
- [How culture Affects Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235309(VS.100).aspx)

And [a search for more info](http://www.bing.com/search?q=string+comparison+localization+site:microsoft.com).

Answer (score 2):

I actually found [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235309(VS.100).aspx) quite useful for this explanation.

For detailed information, have a look at [New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx) seems preety good to me.
I live in Turkey and I know that understanding the turkish İ character will help you understand the concept better.

Comment: Thanks guys, this will keep me busy for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my favorite: [Sorting it all Out](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/)